# hom-set definition of limit?

Tags: category-theory

I've heard of limits of a diagram as a cone with universal property. But on the ncatlab website, they define it as a hom-set. Specifically, for the limit of a set valued functor $F: D^{op}\rightarrow Set,$ we have
$LimF:=Hom_{[D^{op},Set]}(pt,  F)$
where $pt:D^{op}\rightarrow Set$ by $d \mapsto \{*\}.$ They call $pt$ the functor constant on a point. So is $pt$ the constant functor? What is $D^{op}?$ Why is it an opposite category? Usually we have a functor $F:I\rightarrow C,$ where $I$ is the indexing category and can be thought of as a diagram, while $F$ assigns objects to the dots and morphisms in the arrows of the diagram. I don't see how this definition is equivalent to the definition of limit using cones.

Comment: First, you need to understand the definition of morphisms in $[\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$. If you don't like $\mathcal{D}^\mathrm{op}$ you can replace it with $\mathcal{I}$ if you like – there is no difference. Once you do that, it will be quite easy to see the connection with cones.

Comment: In case this is the issue, you could just define the limit of $F:D\to Set$ as $Hom_{[D,Set]}(*,F)$ and not worry about any opposites.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the connection with cones. But I don't get how we have the universal property of limits. Is it because $pt$ is a constant functor so any morphism $f_{i,j} : pt(i) \rightarrow pt(j)$ is an isomorphism? Then each natural transformation in the hom-set would be isomorphic to the other, so the limit is unique up to unique isomorphism.

Comment: Do you know what is a cone? It's a natural transformation between a constant functor and $F$. A natural transformation from $pt$ to $F$ is just a point lying above the image of $F$. To prove that this is the limit you have to show the universal property, but if you have a natural transformation between a constant functor and $F$ you have an element of $\text{lim}F$, so you can factorize through $\text{lim} F$.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I was thinking about it as a collection of maps so we have commutative triangles. I wasn't thinking about the big picture.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $\hat {\mathcal D}$ the category $[\mathcal D^{\mathrm {op}},\mathsf{Set}]$ (we call it the category of *presheaves* on $\mathcal D$). Denote also $\mathfrak h \colon \mathcal D \to \hat{\mathcal D}$ the Yoneda embedding $d \mapsto \hom_{\mathcal D}(-,d)$. Then, for any presheaf $F \colon \mathcal D^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$, Yoneda's lemma states that there is an isomorphism
$$ F \simeq \hom_{\hat{\mathcal D}}(\mathfrak h(-), F) $$
in the category $\hat{\mathcal D}$. So, in $\mathsf{Set}$,
$$ \begin{aligned}
  \lim F &\simeq \lim \hom_{\hat{\mathcal D}}(\mathfrak h(-), F) \\
  &\simeq \hom_{\hat{\mathcal D}}(\operatorname{colim}\mathfrak h(-), F).
\end{aligned}$$
You can go ahead and verify that $\operatorname{colim}\mathfrak h(-)$ is actually the constant presheaf (this is again Yoneda's lemma).